# Did the Valar refer to themselves as Valar or was that just a name given to them?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion, valar

Did the Valar refer to themselves as Valar, or was "Valar" just a name given to them by the Elves because they needed a way to refer to them? Or did Eru name them before they entered into Arda?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name was given by the Elves:

> The Great among these spirits the Elves name the Valar, the Powers of Arda, and Men have often called them gods.
>
> <sup>*The Silmarillion* II *Valaquenta*</sup>

A list of words Quenya borrowed from Valarin is given in *The War of the Jewels*; "vala" is noted thus:

> Vala 'has  power' (sc. over the matter of Ea), 'a  Power'; pl. Valar, 'they  have power, the Powers'. Since these words are from the point of Q[uenyan] structure verbal in origin, they were probably versions of V[alarin] words of  verbal meaning.
>
> <sup>*History of Middle-earth* XI *The War of the Jewels* Part 4: "Quendi and Eldar" Appendix D: "* *Kwen*, *Quenya*, and the Elvish (Especially Ñoldorin) words for 'Language'" Note on the Language of the Valar.</sup>

Whatever word the Valar and Eru use to describe themselves collectively (and they must have such a word) is translated to "Valar" by the Elves, and then by the translator of *The Silmarillion*. Consider, for example:

> Then Manwë awoke, and he went down to Yavanna upon Ezellohar, and he sat beside her beneath the Two Trees. And Manwë said: 'O Kementári, Eru hath spoken, saying: "Do then any of the Valar suppose that I did not hear all the Song, even the least sound of the least voice?
>
> <sup>*The Silmarillion* III *Quenta Silmarillion* Chapter 2: "Of Aulë and Yavanna"</sup>

What relation the Quenya "Valar" has to the Valarin origin is unknown.